# Sharepoint 2010-Project Task List column is read only when configured to allow multiple lines of text

Tags: 2010

I have a project task list set up in SharePoint 2010.  I need to have a column with the type set to allow multiple lines of text so in essence it allows us to wrap text.  Whenever I configure a column to allow multiple lines of text it changes that particular column to read only.  I am thinking this may be a glitch; however, wondered if anyone knows of a fix.

Comment: This may be more thinking out loud than helpful but what you're saying is that the multiple lines of text list column type has the read only permission level by default. Is it possible to edit the permission level of a list column type? Maybe look for a fix in central admin settings. If I had SharePt in front of me right now I'd look around but I hope that helps.